# How can I add a new line character before a pattern?

Tags: unix

I have below file

```
access fw1 10.100.11.224 255.255.255.240 10.185.34.241 255.255.255.240 eq 9011access fw1 10.100.11.228 255.255.255.240 10.190.2.200 255.254.254.254 eq 9000
```

I just want them in new line starting with access. How do I achieve it?

```
access fw1 10.100.11.224 255.255.255.240 10.185.34.241 255.255.255.240 eq 9011
access fw1 10.100.11.228 255.255.255.240 10.190.2.200 255.254.254.254 eq 9000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using perl and negative lookbehind to not add a newline before the first `access`:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<!^)(access)/\n\1/g' file
access fw1 10.100.11.224 255.255.255.240 10.185.34.241 255.255.255.240 eq 9011
access fw1 10.100.11.228 255.255.255.240 10.190.2.200 255.254.254.254 eq 9000
```

Comment: I have to do perl -pe 's/(?<!^)(access)/\n\1/g' file > someotherfile. Is there any way it will modify the actual contents of file without having to re-direct the output to other file in perl?

Comment: Sure, it's the `-i` switch: `perl -pi -e 's/(?<!^)(access)/\n\1/g' file`

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash`, you can use `sed` to accomplish this, and add a `\n` character before each `access`

```
sed 's/access/\n&/g' your_file
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Both of the commands worked fine.

Comment: If this answered your question, accept as an accepted answer.